# dplyr collapse by rank of variable but ignore NA

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am struggling with a collapse of my data.

Basically my data consists of multiple indicators with  multiple observations for each year. I want to convert this to one observation for each indicator for each country.

I have a rank indicator which specifies the sequence by which sequence the observations have to be chosen.

Basically the observation with the first rank (thus  1 instead of 2) has to be chosen, as long as for that rank the value is not NA.

An additional question: The years in my dataset vary over time, thus is there a way to make the code dynamic in the sense that it applies the code to all column names from 1990 to 2025 when they exist?

```
df <- data.frame(country.code = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                        id = as.factor(c("GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "GDP", "CA", "CA", "CA", "GR", "GR", "GR", "GR", "GR")), 
                       `1999` = c(NA,NA,NA, 1000,NA,NA, 100,NA,NA, NA,NA,22), 
                       `2000` = c(NA,NA,1, 2,NA,1, 2,NA,1000, 12,13,2), 
                       `2001` = c(3,100,1, 3,100,20, 1,1,44, 65,NA,NA),
                       rank = c(1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5))
```

The result should be the following dataset:

```
    result <- data.frame(country.code = c(1, 1, 1), 
                         id = as.factor(c("GDP", "CA", "GR")),
                         `1999`= c(1000, 100, 22),
                         `2000`= c(1, 1, 12),
                         `2001`= c(3, 100, 1))
```

I attempted the following solution (but this does not work given the NA's in the data and I would have to specify each column:

```
    test <- df %>% group_by(Country.Code, Indicator.Code) %>% 
                summarise(test1999 = `1999`[which.min(rank))
```

I don't see how I can explain R to omit the cases of the column 1999 that are NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can subset using the minimum rank of the non-null values for a column e.g `x[rank==min(rank[!is.na(x)])]`.

> An additional question: The years in my dataset vary over time,....

Using `summarise_at`, `vars` and `matches` can be used to select any column name with 4 digits i.e. 1990-2025 using a regular expression `[0-9]{4}` (which means search for a digit "0-9" repeated exactly 4 times) and apply the above procedure to them using `funs`

```
librar(dplyr)    
df %>% group_by(country.code,id) %>% 
       summarise(`1999` = `1999`[rank==ifelse(all(is.na(`1999`)),1, min(rank[!is.na(`1999`)]))])

df %>% group_by(country.code,id) %>% 
       summarise_at(vars(matches("[0-9]{4}")),funs(.[rank==ifelse(all(is.na(.)), 1, min(rank[!is.na(.)]))]))

 # A tibble: 3 x 5
 # Groups:   country.code [?]
  country.code id    `1999` `2000` `2001`
         <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1            1 CA       100      1    100
2            1 GDP     1000      1      3
3            1 GR        22     12      1
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However it does not work anymore once there is no data for one of the "id's" in one of the years. When you replace the column 1999 by `1999 = c(NA,NA,NA, NA,NA,NA, 100,NA,NA, NA,NA,22)` it does not work anymore. Any solution that is robust to this?

Comment: @Jan-Pieter thanks for pointing that out. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks allot! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that uses `tidyr::fill` to replace the `NA`s by the first non-`NA` value after we `arrange`d the data by `id` and `rank`. It might not be the most efficient approach because we first `gather` and then `spread` the data again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(id, rank) %>% 
  gather(key, value, X1999:X2001) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(value, .direction = "up") %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  country.code id     rank X1999 X2000 X2001
#         <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1            1 CA        1   100     1   100
#2            1 GDP       1  1000     1     3
#3            1 GR        1    22    12     1
```

NOTE: the column names are not `1999`, `2000` etc. as in your data probably. But that is easily adoptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change dataframe to long form , remove na, select values corresponding to minimum rank and spread back to wide form

```
 library(tidyr)
  test <- df %>%
  gather("Year", "Value", X1999:X2001) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Value))%>%
  group_by(country.code, id, Year) %>% 
  arrange(rank)%>%
  summarise(first(Value)) %>%
  spread(Year, `first(Value)`)
```